# what xpath selector will retrieve both these prices and nothing else?

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I have the following two td elements

```
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="150" STYLE="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial" HEIGHT="65"> <a href="http://www.site.com/page/IDLM/PROD/10001512"><B><i>Brand </i></B><BR>Title</a><BR>
$65.00
 </TD>
 <TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="35">&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="150" STYLE="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial" HEIGHT="65"> <a href="http://www.site.com/page/IDLM/PROD/10001511"><B><i>Brand </i></B><BR>Title</a><BR>
<span style="color: #999999; font-weight: normal;"><strike>$212.00</strike></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<B>$127.20</B>
 </TD>
```

I want to retrieve the final price from both ($65.00 and $127.20). I can use

```
//td/br[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1]|//td/br[last()]/following-sibling::b[1]
```

to return

```
    [0] => 
$65.00

    [1] => Â Â 
    [2] => $127.20
```

where [1] is the `&nbsp;&nbsp;` preceding the second price. Is there an xpath that will retrieve only

```
    [0] => 
$65.00
    [1] => $127.20
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases the text in question is the final non-empty text node descendant. That's how you'd describe it in English; here's how to say it in XPath:

```
//td/descendant::text()[normalize-space()][last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it seems to me that in this particular case,

```
//td/br[last()]/following-sibling::*[last()]
```

may work, because both the text node containing `$65.00` and the `B` node containing `$127.20` are the last of their siblings.

Comment: that returns only the $127.20 price, although I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: @jela hmm, I suspect a `text()` node doesn't get matched by `*`